# If a process started from a setuid binary forks, and the child drops privileges, can the child still be trusted?

Tags: linux, security, fork, setuid

Let's say the following program is executed from a setuid-root binary, by a non-root user:

```c
int main()
{
    if (fork()) {
        /* Parent process */
        int wstatus; wait(&wstatus);
        if (WEXITSTATUS(wstatus) == 0) {
            /* Child process exited with return code indicating success */
            do_something_potentially_dangerous();
            return 0;
        } else {
            /* Child process exited with return code indicating failure */
            puts("Access denied");
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        /* Child process */
        setuid(getuid());
        /*
        ...
        */
        return do_critical_security_check();  /* let's say this returns 0 if it's safe */
    }
}
```

A setuid program normally runs with extra security measures that prevent the user who started it from tampering with its (privileged) execution. I can only assume this status is preserved when it forks a child process.

But when the child process drops root privileges, does it also drop any of this protection? Barring a vulnerability in the child process's code, would the unprivileged user be able to interfere with `do_critical_security_check()`, or otherwise force the child process to return 0 when it shouldn't? (Assume `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope` is set to 0.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ptrace` man page specifies that it will (my emphasis):

> 3. Deny access if *neither* of the following is true:
>
>    - The **real, effective, *and* saved-set** user IDs of the target match the caller's user ID, and the real, effective, and saved-set
>        group IDs of the target match the caller's group ID.
>    - The caller has the `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability in the user namespace of the target.

So if there's a saved UID that's not available to the tracer, then the tracing process can't attach and hijack the child to access it.

If the child drops its EUID irrevocably (using `setresuid()`), then the tracing process can attach, but there's no saved UID to abuse.

Comment: What about through mechanisms other than `ptrace`? `/proc/___/mem` for example. Also, even if there's no saved UID to abuse, remember, the parent process is relying on the child process's exit code for a security-critical decision.

Comment: This also means that a process dropping its EUID irrevocably should make sure any sensitive information is cleared from its memory before doing so, I assume?